# C# expression, VS converts enum to int but not LinqPad

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, linqpad, linq-expressions

Suppose this fairly simple expression:

```
Expression<Func<DayOfWeek, bool>> filter = d => d == DayOfWeek.Friday;
```

In LinqPad I get an `UnaryExpression` for the right part, which is what I want, so I can work with the enum value and type:

[image: Expected result in LinqPad]

However, in a VS, I get a totally different `ConstantExpression` which converts the value to an integer:

[image: Result in VS]

I really have no clue why this is happening. Is there a global setting I'm missing in VS or something?

It happens in VS 2015 AND 2010 as well.

LINQPad 5.02.03

Comment: Maybe related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099809/expressions-breaking-code-when-compiled-using-vs2015-update-1

Comment: I believe it is. However, I don'T know if this question should be marked duplicate since it is explained fairly differently

Comment: I'd say it's the same. Ultimately, the _compiler_ seems to be inlining the underlying value for the enums, even with the debug configuration. If you look at the dissassembly, you can see that the expression is built using a constant int in its place whereas the LINQPad script doesn't. Though, I would have expected that LINQPad is using the same compiler (running LINQPad 5)... or is it done with CodeDom and _that's_ different?

Comment: I can't mark it as duplicate since the other question does not have an accepted answer. In the end I don't care much, as long as we find a solution. In my case I could reverse the conversion back to the enum when I detect either side of the expression as enum but it's kind of ugly and I'd rather not.

Comment: For what it's worth, I get the same `Constant(5)` in LinqPad (v4.57.02).

Comment: I'm using 5.02.03 (latest as of this writing). I've updated the question.